# Solving a differential equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I have to solve this equation $(x+y)\cdot y'=a^2$ by substitution.

I though about $x+y=u$, but how do I do next?

But $u' =(x+y)'= 1 +1 =2$?

Comment: Where did $y'=1$ come from?

Comment: It came from my mind :D

Answer (score 1):

Expressing $y'$ in terms of $u'$ seems like a promising next step.